# how to fix bad decoding?

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, python-unicode

i am using shown below procedure to write (spidered from the web) a list of persons data.
I think the code itself is ok, but i am confused with results. Some chars are decoded properly, some not. For example:

```
STANIS?AWurodzony/a 01.01.1888, ?Ԅ?
HALINAurodzony/a 05.07.1927, ŁÓDŹ
```

the last word in both strings is the same!
Also ? sign used to replace non-translatable chars once is used once not:

```
STANISŁAWurodzony/a 24.03.1907, RAKSZANY
      ^
      | here is written ok - not replaced
```

And here is the code:

```
def findPerson():
    file = codecs.open('Names.txt','a','ISO-8859-1','replace')
    try:
        with codecs.open('./listNames_links.txt','r','ISO-8859-1','replace') as f:
            line = f.readline()
            while line != '':
                #print line,
                line = f.readline() 
                res = requests.get('http://real.address.gov.pl'+line)
                res.raise_for_status()
                soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text)
                linkElems = soup.find('a','css_class_name').text
                file.write(linkElems)
                file.write('\r\n')#preserve end-of-line
```

**question:**
How to fix this. Is my procedure wrong? Or the source page has broken encoding? (I suppose it is ok, i can read it in browser without any errors.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a polish language, and doesn't look like multi-byte encoding such as `UTF-8` is used. You are writing to your `Names.txt` file using `ISO-8859-1` which doesn't support all polish characters.

You could use `ISO-8859-2` for Polish characgter support, but even better would be to use `UTF-8` which supports all languages and is the common standard on the web.

Try

```
file = codecs.open('Names.txt','a','UTF-8','replace')
```

When you make a request using Requests, try checking the encoding of each page. For example:

```
res = requests.get('http://real.address.gov.pl'+line)
res.encoding = 'utf-8' 
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text)
```

Comment: I know, this is the right solution, I tried this, but the problem is that the results differs with each execution of the code.

Comment: I just saw your comment - is this fixed? If not, plz confirm if the two lines `ŁÓDŹ` and `?Ԅ?` come from two different URL locations.

Comment: you're right, those are different locations: birth places of two different persons found with two different requests. But all the data comes from one database. Did you ever work with requests module? Variable **line** in code can looks like:**' /listNames.do?idx=Ś&katalogId=2&pageNo=1&nameId=007&'**

Comment: I forgot to undrscore: the same word is sometimes written properly sometimes not. It looks like data transfer error, but is possible at all?

Comment: This is very strange. So the exact same person's data is sometimes encoded differently with each execution? - Check my updated answer.

Comment: with call to unicode I am getting "TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported". Perhaps due to I am using v.3 of BeautifulSoup (with Python2.7.10)
I checked resource encoding earlier, it is ISO-8859-1 for every request response.

Comment: It seems that Requests will try to auto detect the encoding, and is wrong some of the time in your case. Please do `res.encoding = 'utf-8'` and then try `BeautifulSoup(res.text)`

Comment: I fetched over 15000 names :D and all are written properly, so this last tip was the **correct solution**. Thank you. (Admins: I know, no thanks, but... :D)
So if i am correct, requests module wrongly recognises the coding and we have to force the proper coding.

Comment: Yes, requests tries to detect the encoding heuristically - it won't actually decode the HTML and read the tags for the UTF-8 encoding. The documentation suggests you do this yourself by parsing `res.content` (a raw string) first: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-content

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very familiar with python, but had similar problems with java programs. And in almost every case it was the problem that not the same encoding was used in all steps and thus while converting it results in ugly charcters.

I'd suggest to use UTF-8 during the whole process if possible.

An off-topic side remark: Because I stumpled upon this so very often, I bought myself [this T-Shirt](http://image.spreadshirtmedia.net/image-server/v1/products/123781404/views/1,width=190,height=190.png/scheiss-encoding.png) (correctly spelled *Scheiß*, German for *crap*) and wear it at work ;-)